# PLC Siemens: Opening file of TIA V13 on TIA V14

Tags: plc

I have a problem of opening a TIA v13 on v14. I tried to migrate the file form migration tool on v14 but when I browse on the project file, it can't be shown.
Can anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your migrated file must be *.am13 *.s7p or .*hmi, you are trying to open *.ap13 or *.ap14